# RxJava io thread waking up UI thread very late after getting http response

Tags: android, rx-java2, okhttp

I am working on a map view. This map view is updated with the locations of relevant events when a button is pressed. This event information is received by the AWS appsyncclient API. However, main UI thread is woken up after about ~3 seconds on an average once http response is received as can be seen in the logs. Is this normal? Can the main UI thread be woken up faster than this?

API call is below:

```
public void getEventsList(Consumer<MutableLiveData<ApiResponse>> listConsumer) {
    System.setProperty("rx2.io-priority", "" + (Thread.MAX_PRIORITY));
    disposables.add(eventSDK.SearchByMyRegion(String.valueOf(eventManager.getCurrentLatLng().latitude), eventManager.getLatitudeDelta(), String.valueOf(eventManager.getCurrentLatLng().longitude), eventManager.getLongitudeDelta())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe(d -> {
                this.responseLiveData.setValue(ApiResponse.loading());
                listConsumer.accept(this.responseLiveData);
            })
            .doOnEvent((data, throwable) -> {
                this.responseLiveData.setValue(ApiResponse.terminate());
                listConsumer.accept(this.responseLiveData);
            })
            .subscribe(event -> {
                if (event != null) {
                    if (event.SearchByMyRegion() != null) {
                        this.responseLiveData.setValue(ApiResponse.success(event.SearchByMyRegion().stores()));
                        listConsumer.accept(this.responseLiveData);
                    }
                } else {
                     this.responseLiveData.setValue(ApiResponse.success(event.SearchByMyRegion().stores()));
                     listConsumer.accept(this.responseLiveData);
                }
            }, error -> {
                this.responseLiveData.setValue(ApiResponse.error(error));
                listConsumer.accept(this.responseLiveData);
            }));
```

Note: okhttp networking library, AWS appsyncclient is used along with RxJava2.

Logcat logs:

```
**05-20 00:29:58.228 18828-19554/com.test.beta E/test: start of network call**
**05-20 00:29:58.233 18828-19136/com.test.beta D/OkHttp: --> POST https://example.com/graphql http/1.1 (1934-byte body)**
05-20 00:29:58.234 18828-19136/com.test.beta D/RetryInterceptor: Retry Interceptor called
05-20 00:29:58.234 18828-19136/com.test.beta D/AppSyncSigV4SignerInterceptor: Signer Interceptor called
05-20 00:29:59.559 18828-19136/com.test.beta I/RetryInterceptor: Returning network response: success
**05-20 00:29:59.559 18828-19136/com.test.beta D/OkHttp: <-- 200**  https://example.com/graphql (1325ms, 43055-byte body)
05-20 00:30:01.811 18828-19045/com.test.beta V/AppSyncOfflineMutationInterceptor: Thread:[388265]: processing Mutations
05-20 00:30:01.812 18828-19045/com.test.beta V/QueueUpdateHandler: Thread:[388265]: Got message to take action on the mutation queue.
    Thread:[388265]: Got message to process next mutation if one exists.
05-20 00:30:01.816 18828-19045/com.test.beta V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[388265]:Persistent mutations queue is EMPTY!. Will check inMemory Queue next
05-20 00:30:01.817 18828-19045/com.test.beta V/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[388265]: In Memory mutations queue was EMPTY!. Nothing to process, exiting
**05-20 00:30:02.256 18828-19136/com.test.beta E/test: response received**
```

Comment: Why do you use `Schedulers.newThread()` instead of `Schedulers.io()`?

Comment: I was testing with Schedulers.newThread(), but actually I am using Schedulers.io().

Comment: @Benjamin: Looks like this is expected no? Looks like scheduler io thread is taking time to wake up main UI thread.

Comment: For me the main thread gets notified in matter of couple milliseconds. 3 seconds is definitely way too long.